# Android-Espresso test a ProgressDialog is displayed and then dismissed

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have a situation when I show a progress-dialog when data is being fetched in the background (either from local room database or from an API endpoint).

Once the data fetching is done (either completed successfully or with an error), we dismiss the progress dialog.

I need to test this scenario using Espresso.

Here are the steps I need to verify.

1. A button (Download data) is visible. (I have done this using `onView(withText("Download data")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`
2. Press the button. (`onView(withText("Download data")).perform(click());`)
3. Verify the progress dialog appears. (`onView(withText("Downloading data")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`)
4. Verify the progress dialog is dismissed after a few seconds (When data fetching is done.)

I can't find a way to achieve the 4th task.

Update 1:
Currently I'm doing it this patchy way:

```
do{
    try{
        onView(withText("Downloading data")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
    catch(NoMatchingViewException e){
        break;
    }
}while(true)
```

This way, progress-Dialog should appear atleast once, then when application dismisses the dialog, the loop breaks.

I'm looking for best / recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Need one clarification on your question, how are you dismissing the dialog

1. is it automatic once data fetch is done
2. you are giving some button for the same.

In first scenario you can put Boolean variable and mark it as true before dismissing the dialog. and after some time check its value.

For second scenario you need to look for the button.

Hope this helps.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no button to dismiss the dialog. It is dismissed programatically once the data fetching is completed. User can not dismiss the dialog. Moreover, I'm verifying the existence of progress dialog as you suggested (I've mentioned that in the question itself). Doing this way will result in assertion failure and the test case is going to fail, which should not happen.